# Endianess Related to processor or data type

Tags: c, endianness

I am working with little endian processor PIC 32 and am looking at a variable that is of type BOOL. One variable is initialized to TRUE and the other as false.

```
static BOOL A = TRUE;
BOOL static B = FALSE;
```

In Memory when I look in memory for variable A, it shows
[image: 32 bit TRUE]

It looks like the processor just assigns a 32 bit number for true and false and not 8 bits so that means its processor dependent. 
For an array of 6 elements of type BOOL, all set to TRUE. How would it be read? Is it going to show up as 6 elements of what is shown in the picture above?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: How do you know it allocates 32-bits? That looks like an 8-bit bool followed by three other things that are zero, like `B` being false.

Comment: Is is C standard and implementation dependant

Comment: C doesn't define a type `BOOL`. It defines `_Bool`, and `stdbool.h` defines `bool`. What does your `BOOL` typedef look like?

Comment: Although you are allowed (at the moment) to write `int long unsigned const long static u = 23;`, you shouldn't do that.  Interestingly, GCC 7.1.0 when run with `-Werror -Wold-style-declaration` doesn't allow it: `error: ‘static’ is not at beginning of declaration [-Werror=old-style-declaration]`.  (And `-Wextra` includes `-Wold-style-declaration` (at least in GCC 7.1.0), so you don't have to add it separately.)

Comment: Endianess is way of Read/Write data with processor. A LE processor like x86 architecture data stored in Memory by CPU in reverse order. unsigned int a = 0x1234; store in 3412 order. (unsigned int : 16 bit). LE reverse byte order when storing on Memory (RAM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOL` is not a standard type. Depending on how it is defined in your environment, probably via a `typedef` in a header file, it may be any integer type, including `unsigned char` which would use 1 byte or `int` which may use 4 bytes on your system and other sizes for other architectures.